# Magento is not showing error if I set duplicate SKU

Tags: php, magento

I have a requirement where I have to update Magento products from outside of Magento code (a CodeIgniter project).

Everything is working perfectly, but, one thing is wrong, if I save 2 products with same SKU, my code does not throw exception.

While if I go to my Magento website's admin section and try to set a duplicate SKU for any product, it does show error that SKU cannot be duplicated.

But why the following code is allowing me to set duplicate SKU? I am posting only relevant code here.

```
   try {
        $url = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $product_name);
        $url = strtolower($url);

        $simpleProduct
                ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
                ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
                ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
                ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
                ->setSku($_POST['sku']) //SKU
                ->setName($_POST['product_name']) //product name
                ->setUrlKey($_POST['url_key'])
                ->setBrand($_POST['brand'])->setType($_POST['type'])
                ->setStatus($_POST['status'] == 1 ? 1 : 2) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
                ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
                ->setNewsFromDate(strtotime('now')) //product set as new from
                ->setNewsToDate(strtotime('+1 week')) //product set as new to
                ->setPrice($_POST['price']) //price in form 11.22
                ->setCost($_POST['price']) //price in form 11.22
                ->setSpecialPrice($_POST['discount_price'])

                ->setMetaTitle($_POST['meta_title'])
                ->setMetaKeyword($_POST['meta_keyword'])
                ->setMetaDescription($_POST['meta_description'])
                ->setDescription($_POST['description'])
                ->setShortDescription($_POST['short_description'])
                ->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'max_sale_qty' => $_POST['quantity'], //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'is_in_stock' => $_POST['quantity'] == 0 ? 0 : 1, //Stock Availability
                    'qty' => $_POST['quantity'] //qty
                        )
                )
                ->setCategoryIds(unserialize($_POST['product_groups_category_map'])); //assign product to categories

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        $simpleProduct->save($simpleProduct);

        if (!empty($_POST['product_groups_images'])) {
            if ($_POST['id_in_magento'] != 0) {
                $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");
                $mediaApiItems = $mediaApi->items($simpleProduct->getId());

                foreach ($mediaApiItems as $item) {
                    $datatemp = $mediaApi->remove($simpleProduct->getId(), $item['file']);
                }
            }

            $simpleProduct->load($_POST['id_in_magento']);
            $simpleProduct->setMetaTitle($_POST['meta_title']);

            foreach (unserialize($_POST['product_groups_images']) as $img) {
                $simpleProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($img, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
            }
        }
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        $simpleProduct->save($simpleProduct);

        $return['magento_id'] = $simpleProduct->getId();
        $return['url_key'] = $simpleProduct->getUrlKey();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        $return['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
```

What is wrong with code?

**PS:**

I repeat that if I try to set duplicate SKU from backend of Magento website, it shows a normal error that SKU cannot be duplicate.

Comment: Because in the code for the back end of magneto, when you try to set a duplicate SKU they are checking to make sure it is not a duplicate and showing you the error message yet your code is not.

Comment: @Anigel Illogical comment

Comment: What is illogical about it? To generate an error message you need to check the error condition. You are not doing that or at least there is nothing in the code you have shown that checks if the SKU already exists before you add it.

Comment: By default Magento's behaviour, shouldn't it show throw exception if I try to set duplicate SKU?

Answer (score 2):

You can check **sku** before adding new product it will solve you issue

```
$sku = 'sku_here';
$p_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
if ($p_id) {
   //sku exists
}
else {
   //sku does not exist
}
```

Comment: but bro why should I check SKU separately? why magento does not throw exception when setting a duplicate SKU?